# how to set IE not load image using webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver

I am now doing the web automated testing using webdriver, to speed the loading, i don't want IE browser loading the pictures.
So if there is any way to set the IE, not firefox or chrome, do not load the pictures?
Thank you.

Comment: i want automatically set it by code, not by hand

Comment: @vasanth - Please stop suggesting edits like this. Backticks should only be used for inline code, not product and tool names. The extra bolding and italics don't make the post any easier to read, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank Spyder_Says_hi very much, this problem resloved.
the solution is to modify registry "HKEY_USERS\sid\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" to "no", and sid is windows user session which can be get by "whoami /user"

Comment: the registry key is "Display Inline Images"

Answer (score 1):

Press the "Alt" key while viewing Internet Explorer to display the browser menu bar.

Click "Tools" and select "Internet Options."

Click the "Advanced" tab.

Uncheck "Show Pictures" from the Multimedia section in the Settings list.

Click "OK."

[Source](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/turn-off-images-internet-explorer-14601.html).

Comment: but what i want is automatically by code, not by hand.

Comment: Oh, I see. My apologies for misunderstanding the question. Do you have any code you have worked on so far? Also, which web driver are you using?

Comment: @zhuxy - What language are you using for your code?

Comment: sorry for my late. i use java to develop the automatic script